# SUMIFS statement based on a name and date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a column that lists names and a column that list dates with time (i.e. 10/17/2022  1:23:00 PM that displays in the cell as 10/17/2022 13:23).

I am looking to sum a column based upon two factors, the name and date but how do I simplify the second factor to be just the date instead of the date and time?

[image]

Currently, in column "G" I have a formula of
=IFERROR(LEFT($B2,FIND("h",$B2)-1),0)*60+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("m",$B2)),TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(RIGHT($B2,LEN($B2)-FIND("h",$B2)),$B2),"m","")),0)
so that I get a number in column G.

I want to sum any of the cells from column G if column A has the parameter of "Matthew" and column C has the parameter of 10/17/2022"

I would then end up having the parameters be entered from a separate location so that I could enter the varying name and date parameters to have the results calculated from the source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ScottCraner pointed out in the comments, in order to use:

```
SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)
```

`criteria_rangeN` *must be a range*, so we cannot use `INT(B2:B9)` to remove the time portion of the data & time data as a criteria range. Excel stores date & time information as a decimal number, where the integer part is the date information.

### Updated Solution

A way to overcome this limitation and being able to use `INT` to remove the time part would be to use `FILTER(array,include,[if_empty])` because `include` is a Boolean array (not a range), therefore in cell `F2`:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C2:C9, (INT(B2:B9)=E3) * (A2:A9=E2)))
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

where `E3` is a date (not date & time), if that is not the case then use in the formula `INT(E3)` instead.

Comment: That formula will not work.  1.  You do not do `A2:A1000=[name]` it should be `A2:A1000,[name]` 2. `INT(C2:C1000)` cannot be done in a SUMIFS as it returns an array and SUMIFS only allows ranges.

Comment: I see your edit and it took care of #1, but you cannot do `INT(C2:C1000)` it must be a range.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraneri could not test it because I didn’t have the data from the question. I am pretty sure I use this approach on a similar problem (this is a typical Jira output). Let me review it and update it if that was the case it worked. That is why it is better to test something before posting an answer, this is the first time I did from the top of my head

Comment: a simple test.  Fill A1:A10 with `1` then B1:B10 with `1.5` then try: `=SUMIFS(A:A,INT(B:B),1)` it will error. https://imgur.com/a/Pxwo8XB

Comment: @ScottCraner yes, it has to be a range, I used it this idea, but not with `SUMIFS`.  Let me think if there is a way to achieve it, if not then I will delete the answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner please check my updated answer I found a way to use `INT` but with `FILTER`. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248892/discussion-between-david-leal-and-scott-craner).

Answer (score 3):

Use SUMPRODUCT()

```
=SUMPRODUCT(G2:G500*(A2:A500="Matthew")*(INT(C2:C500)=DATE(2022,10,17))
```

or use SUMIFS with bookends:

```
=SUMIFS(G2:G500,A2:A500,"Matthew",C2:C500,">="&DATE(2022,10,17),C2:C500,"<"&DATE(2022,10,17)+1)
```